# FTP server with GUI for Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gui, ftp

I need to setup a FTP sever on my PC running Ubuntu 13.10. FileZilla is great for connecting to FTP severs but their FTP host is Windows only. When I looked for software on Google I only got command line tools.

Is there a good FTP server host with a GUI for Ubuntu?

It needs to:

- Work on Ubuntu 13.10
- Be free
- Have a GUI
- Preferably be easy to use

Comment: Who said Filezilla's FTP host is Windows only? I use Filezilla on Ubuntu and it works great.

Answer (score 7):

A while ago, I've used **[ProFTPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProFTPD)**, which is also [recommended at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/58635/68291) for offering a nice and user-friendly GUI:

[image: GAdmin-ProFTPD]
<sup>*GAdmin-ProFTPD* (source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProFTPD); click image for larger variant)</sup>

- *Work on Ubuntu 13.10:* [yes](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/gadmin-proftpd)
- *Free:* Yes
- *GUI:* Yes (see screenshot)
- *Easy to use:* [yes](https://askubuntu.com/q/58635/68291)

I have to admit I never used the GUI myself. But *ProFTPD* itself always was running stable, and did what I expected.

Having said that: *GAdmin-ProFTPD* is not the only GUI available for *ProFTPD*. You can find a long list of additional candidates [at DebianHelp](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/proftpweb.htm). So yes, *ProFTPD* should be a good candidate you definitely should take a look at. Help for it naturally is available [on our sister-site "AskUbuntu"](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=proftpd).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gnome then you might use your default file manager, that is, Nautilus.

For Ubuntu version 13.10, you can go to **File** menu > choose **Connect to Server...** and type in the server you want to connect to.

[image: Connect to Server GUI]

Comment: This seems to be a client, not a server interface